# Switching Storybook from Webpack to Vite in Gatsby app

Tags: vite, storybook

I work on a Gatsby project and I'm hoping to run our Storybook with Vita instead of our existing Webpack setup. I'm clearly not doing it right.

I added the plugins:

```
"@storybook/builder-vite": "^0.4.2",
"@vitejs/plugin-react": "^3.1.0",
"vite": "^4.1.1",
```

I also added our aliases by importing my `tsconfig`and converting the `paths` to the right format.

Although most of my attempts to run it resulted in about 1000 instances of

```
Failed to resolve import "react/jsx-dev-runtime" from "react/jsx-dev-runtime". Does the file exist?
```

it's actually running now. And it booted up WAY faster than it used to.

The only issue appears to be that it's not reloading, not at all. I make a change in a component, or a change in a story, and there is zero output in the terminal running storybook.

Although I do notice that this run, although it looks like it's working in the browser, does still give only these two errors:

```
Failed to resolve dependency: react/jsx-runtime, present in 'optimizeDeps.include'
Failed to resolve dependency: react/jsx-dev-runtime, present in 'optimizeDeps.include'
```

How can I fix this? I'm so close!

---

I've tried...

```js
const react = require('@vitejs/plugin-react');

//...
module.exports = {
  // ...
  async viteFinal(config) {
    return mergeConfig(config, {
      // is this where this goes?
      plugins: [
        react({
          jsxRuntime: 'classic',
        }),
      ],
      resolve: { alias: aliasPathsVite },
      },
    })
  },
}
```

Which does open Storybook in the browser, but it doesn't load, and the terminal gives endless instances of:

```
10:30:38 AM [vite] Internal server error: Transform failed with 2 errors:
Typography/Links.tsx:3:4: ERROR: The symbol "prevRefreshReg" has already been declared
Typography/Links.tsx:4:4: ERROR: The symbol "prevRefreshSig" has already been declared
  Plugin: vite:esbuild
  File: Typography/Links.tsx:1:42

  The symbol "prevRefreshReg" has already been declared
  1  |  import RefreshRuntime from "/@react-refresh";let prevRefreshReg;let prevRefreshSig;if (import.meta.hot) {  if (!window.__vite_plugin_react_preamble_installed__) {    throw new Error(      "@vitejs/plugin-react can't detect preamble. Something is wrong. " +      "See https://github.com/vitejs/vite-plugin-react/pull/11#discussion_r430879201"    );  }  prevRefreshReg = window.$RefreshReg$;  prevRefreshSig = window.$RefreshSig$;  window.$RefreshReg$ = (type, id) => {    RefreshRuntime.register(type, "Typography/Links.tsx" + " " + id)  };  window.$RefreshSig$ = RefreshRuntime.createSignatureFunctionForTransform;}var _jsxFileName = "Typography/Links.tsx";
  2  |  import RefreshRuntime from "/@react-refresh";
  3  |  let prevRefreshReg;
     |      ^
  4  |  let prevRefreshSig;
  5  |  if (import.meta.hot) {

  The symbol "prevRefreshSig" has already been declared
  2  |  import RefreshRuntime from "/@react-refresh";
  3  |  let prevRefreshReg;
  4  |  let prevRefreshSig;
     |      ^
  5  |  if (import.meta.hot) {
  6  |    if (!window.__vite_plugin_react_preamble_installed__) {

      at failureErrorWithLog (node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1604:15)
      at node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:837:29
      at responseCallbacks.<computed> (node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:701:9)
      at handleIncomingPacket (node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:756:9)
      at Socket.readFromStdout (node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:677:7)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
      at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
      at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
      at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
      at Pipe.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)
```

---

I've tried...

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  async viteFinal(config) {
    return mergeConfig(config, {
      resolve: {
        alias: {
          ...aliasPathsVite,
          'react/jsx-runtime': path.join(
            __dirname,
            'node-modules/react/jsx-runtime'
          ),
        },
        optimizeDeps: {
          include: ['react/jsx-runtime']
        }
      },
    })
  },
}
```

which opens a non-working Storybook in the browser, and the terminal says this hundreds of times

```
Failed to resolve import "react/jsx-dev-runtime" from "react/jsx-dev-runtime". Does the file exist?
```

Then some of these:

```
[vite] error while updating dependencies:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'node_modules/.vite-storybook/deps_temp' -> 'node_modules/.vite-storybook/deps'
    at renameSync (node:fs:1030:3)
    at Object.commit (file:///node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-3007b26d.js:42874:19)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async commitProcessing (file:///node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-3007b26d.js:42348:17)
    at async runOptimizer (file:///node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-3007b26d.js:42386:17)
```

And then a bunch of issues importing CSS files, like this one

```
10:45:29 AM [vite] Internal server error: Failed to resolve import "./header.css" from "node_modules/@storybook/mdx1-csf/dist/esm/stories/Header.js?v=ec48b265". Does the file exist?
```

Comment: I found a reference that gives color to my answer below here: hhttps://github.com/remix-run/remix/issues/8590#issuecomment-1908261434

Basically, in my case, the other plugins I was using already bundled "react", so when i added "react", it was giving me those errors.
<br >
Double check and see that your other plugins aren't also silently loading react and causing it to blow up.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this?

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    'react/jsx-runtime': 'react/jsx-runtime.js',
  },
},
```

*Source: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/6215*

Also:

```
optimizeDeps.include: ['react/jsx-runtime']
```

Another way can be tweaking the configuration of `@vitejs/plugin-react`:

```
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react({
      jsxRuntime: 'classic',
    }),
  ]
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I was excited about these, but both gave their own problems. See my update I'm about to post for details.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this same issue Johnathan while migrating from the classic remix config to vite@5.1.6

TLDR; Remove the vite react plugin entirely -- I found this solution here:

```js
export default defineConfig({
  // ... other config options
  plugins: [
    remix({
      ignoredRouteFiles: ['**/.*'],
    }),
    tsconfigPaths(),
    // react(), <--- remove this and any configs you have for it
  ],
  // ... more config options
});
```

After that it's smooth sailing ⛵️

I was getting these errors:

```bash
8:46:30 AM [vite] Internal server error: Transform failed with 3 errors:
/Users/s-k/dev/console/app/root.tsx:4:7: ERROR: The symbol "RefreshRuntime" has already been declared
/Users/s-k/dev/console/app/root.tsx:5:4: ERROR: The symbol "prevRefreshReg" has already been declared
/Users/s-k/dev/console/app/root.tsx:6:4: ERROR: The symbol "prevRefreshSig" has already been declared
```

Why this works:
see here: https://github.com/remix-run/remix/issues/8590#issuecomment-1908261434

Basically, in my case, the other plugin I was using, "remix", already bundles "react", so when I added "react", it was giving me those errors.

Double check and see that your other plugins aren't also silently loading react and causing it to blow up.

Hope that helps